# Fetch the unique rows from postgres database as per longest unique path in ltree

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-11, ltree

I am working over postgres in db we have below table where we have `PATH` column  as `ltree` for storing hierarchy ids.

Table (Location)-

```
| ID(PK) |   User   |PATH (parent hierarchy) |
|--------|----------|---------|
|    1   |  Parent  |   null  |
|    2   |  Child-1 |   1     |
|    3   |  Child-2 |   1.2   |
|    4   |  Child-3 |   1.2.3 |
|    5   |  AParent |   null  |
|    6   |  AChild-2|   5     |
|    7   |  AChild-3|   5.6   |
|    8   |  AChild-4|   5.6   |
```

tried below query -

```
select loc.user,STRING_TO_ARRAY(concat(loc.PATH::text,'.',loc.id),'.') as path
from location loc
WHERE LOC.NAME ilike '%child%';
```

Result -

```
|   ID   |   User   |   PATH  |
|--------|----------|---------|
|    2   |  Child-1 |{1,2}    |
|    3   |  Child-2 |{1,2,3}  |
|    4   |  Child-3 |{1,2,3,4}|
|    6   |  AChild-2|{5,6}    |
|    7   |  AChild-3|{5,6,7}  |
|    8   |  AChild-4|{5,6,8}  |
```

Here you can see we have multiple hierarchies in the table but i want the unique hierarchies till the leaf
e.g.

```
Hierarchy -1
A>B>C
Hierarchy -2
A>B>C>D`
```

expected result should be -

```
   A>B>C>D
```

cause A>B>C also comes under same umbrella.
so the final table expected result -

```
|   ID   |   User   |   PATH   |
|--------|----------|----------|
|    4   |  Child-3 |{1,2,3,4} |
|    7   |  AChild-3|{5,6,7}   |
|    8   |  Child-4 |{5,6,8}   |
```

Same table managing the parent-child relationship as path showing the hierarchy of user.

Please let me know if anything else required.

Comment: Your example data in the first table doesn't match your subsequent example output.

Comment: What is the link between parents and children ?

Comment: @Philippe updated the summary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find leaves by examining whether a node has any descendants:

```sql
select *
from location l1
where l1.path is not null
and not exists (
    select from location l2
    where l2.path <@ l1.path 
    and l2.path <> l1.path
    )
order by l1.id
```

Test it in [db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=642823ddc850193ff9707a38eecc47ad)

The query is more complex than it could be because your use of `ltree` is somewhat unlogical. Roots should not be `null`, all the hierarchy information should be included in the `ltree` column, while you unnecessary mixed it with `id`.

Comment: Thanks  @Klin for quick and valuable response also want to ask what should be the root value as you mentioned it shouldn;t be `null`..

Comment: Well, if a root is `1` then its descendants are `1.1`, `1.2` etc. It would be simpler and more logical. One of the basic practices in SQL is not to use the primary key to have additional meaning. However, your approach is not bad if you are able to use it consequently.

Comment: Thanks @klin, i also want to include the row where path is null and not be a part of any hierarchy

Comment: tried below query working well please let me know if you have any better version of query - `select id,name,path
from location l1
where not exists (
    select from location l2
    where text2ltree(CONCAT_WS('.',ltree2text(l2.path),l2.id)) <@ text2ltree(CONCAT_WS('.',ltree2text(loc.path),loc.id)) and 
 text2ltree(CONCAT_WS('.',ltree2text(l2.path),l2.id))<> text2ltree(CONCAT_WS('.',ltree2text(loc.path),loc.id)))
order by l1.id`